# pouchDB and Backand, offline and online sync

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I'm working on an ionic project. So, I would like to ask, if I can manage to integrate pouchDB with [back**and**](https://www.backand.com/) (not backend). To have an application that can sync online and offline data. Because what I found is that, pouchDB works perfectly with couchDB. But I'm looking a free backend service.

I hope my question is clear.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can via pouchdb sync, [an example](http://blog.couchbase.com/sync-with-couchbase-using-only-angularjs-and-pouchdb) and a couchbase [server](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads) 
It will handle all the off-line storage & server storage CRUD synchronization 
I am working on a similar project using that example github.com/Yemeni/lvlacc

Comment: But can you connect couchDB with backand (www.backand.com)

Comment: My bad, I read your question as "back end" instead of "backand" ;D, so my friend I have no answer for that.

Comment: I have tried SSDB with levelDB, the problem is I had to do all the repositories for sessions & connections my self.